# Is there a way to exclude fatal warnings from unit tests?

Tags: scala

I would like to turn fatal warnings on for my project but exclude fatal warnings for for my unit tests. I am currently cross compiling to Scala 2.12 and 2.13 (also ignoring deprecation warnings) and these are my current compiler flags within build.sbt

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-language:_",
  "-target:11",
  "-encoding",
  "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-language:existentials",
  "-language:higherKinds",
  "-language:implicitConversions",
  "-unchecked",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-Ywarn-numeric-widen",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard"
) ++ (CrossVersion.binaryScalaVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
  case "2.12" =>
    Seq(
      "-Xlint",
      "-Yno-adapted-args",
      "-Xfuture",
      "-Ypartial-unification"
    )
  case "2.13" =>
    Seq(
      "-Wconf:cat=deprecation:w,any:e", // exclude deprecations in fatal warnings
      "-Xlint:-byname-implicit" // needed for Doobie
    )
  case _ => Nil
})
```

Comment: You can consider using `@nowarn` in tests to suppress the warnings. It was introduced in 2.12+ here https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8373

Comment: Have you consider just using **sbt-tpolecat**?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```scala
Test / scalacOptions -= "-Xfatal-warnings"
```

Comment: I'll need to come back to this. I'm running into a strange issue where fatal warnings isn't working for my normal project and only activating on my tests for some reason